# maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments

Tags: symfony, shopware

i created a Service to reading data from the Datebase, in order to achieve that,  i want to make a Controller and throw this controller i want to call first the ReadingData  Service. however get the Bug :
Could not resolve argument $ReadingDatan of "TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller\PageController::showexample()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?

my codes :

ReadingData.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace TryPlugin\Service;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;


class ReadingData
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function readData(Context $context): void
    {
        $products = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria(), $context);
    }

    /*    public function readData(Context $context): void
        {
            $product = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria([$myId]), $context)->first();
        }*/


}
```

PageController.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller;

use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\LoginRequired;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use TryPlugin\Service\ReadingData;


/**
 * @RouteScope (scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class PageController extends StorefrontController
{
 
    /**
     * @Route("/examples", name="examples", methods={"GET"})
     */


    public function showExample(ReadingData $ReadingDatan): Response
    {
        $meinData = $ReadingDatan->readData();

        return new Response($meinData);
 
    }
}
```

Service.xml:

```
<service id="TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller\PageController" public="true">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>

    </call>
</service>

<!--ReadingDate From Controller-->
<service id="TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller\ProductController" public="true">
    <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
</service>
```

Comment: In order to inject services arguments into a controller action you do indeed need to tag the controller service with controller.service_arguments.  You can check the docs on how to tag services.  Nowadays this sort of thing is usually handled by autowire but manual configuration works as well.

Comment: And once you the controller wired then you will need to fix the readData($context) issue.  Might be a good time to stop and read the first sections on the service container just to get an idea of what dependency injection is and what services are.  Be sure to read the docs for your Symfony version.  You are definitely doing things the 'old style' way.

Comment: Add <tag name="controller.service_arguments"/> to your controller in xml it should solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use autowire just add the tag how the error says

```xml
<service id="TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller\PageController" public="true">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>

    </call>
    <tag name="controller.service_arguments"/>
</service>

<service id="TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller\ProductController" public="true">
    <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
    <tag name="controller.service_arguments"/>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the ReadingData service is not known by symfony, as mentioned by Cerad new symfony versions handle this with autowire, but not in shopwaree 6. You need to register it in your services.xml. Just like described here.

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-custom-service

Or use the suggested tag controller.service_arguments.